# SSIS Compare tables content and update another

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

I would like to compare two tables, one from Access Mdb & one SQL server table is SSIS.

The goal is to truncate the table if there is differences and fill it with MDB source and Update the version in another table.

I am trying to do it through a lookup but the Version is incremented with the number of rows and it should be once.

The operation needs to be performed with 2 different Tables.

Comment: What's the question?  How to not have the version incremented by the number of rows?

Comment: How am I supposed to perform only once the update even if I have 10 No Match output rows ?

Comment: ah, gotcha.  i'll put that in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to perform only once the update even if I have 10 No
>   Match output rows ?

SSIS provides the OLEDB Command for performing in the pipeline updates in a data flow.  However, as you have implied in your question, this performs an UPDATE command per row.

A more efficient technique for performing batch level updates is to:

1. Truncate UPDATE staging table
2. Detect what rows have changed in the data flow
3. Direct changed rows to a destination and store the data in a staging table
4. Add an execute SQL command after the data flow which will perform an update from the staging table to the target table.  i.e.

   ```
   UPDATE T
   SET T.Column1 = S.Column1
       , T.Column2 = S.Column2
   FROM MyTarget T 
       JOIN MySource S ON T.id = S.id
   ```

The Control flow will look like this:

[image]

EDIT:  Edited Steps and image to add a step for truncating the staging table.

Comment: Yes but in this case it will be updated everytimes I goes into the package, even if there is no update performed and I would like to avoid it. Thx

Comment: Truncate the staging table before each run.  This way it will only be empty if there are no updates.  I will update the image to explain that