# update target table given DateCreated and DateUpdated columns in source table

Tags: ssis

What is the most efficient way of updating a target table given the fact that the source table contains a DateTimeCreated and DateTimeUpdated column?

Comment: By Date?  Could you form a more specific question?  How is this related to SSIS?

Comment: Quite easy really. I would like to keep the source in target in synch avoiding a truncate. I am looking for a bets practice pattern in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to keep the source in target in synch avoiding a
>   truncate. I am looking for a bets practice pattern in this situation

I'll avoid a best practice answer but give enough detail to make an appropriate choice.  There are two main methods with which you might update a table in SSIS, avoiding a TRUNCATE - LOAD:

1) Use an `OLEBD COMMAND`

This method is good if:

- you have a reliable DateTimeUpdated column,
- there are not many rows to update,
- there are not a lot of columns to update
- there are not many added columns in the dataflow (i.e. derived column transforms)
- and the update statement is fairly straightforward.

This method performs poorly with many columns because it performs a row-by-row update.  Relying on an audit date column can be a great method to reduce the number of rows to update, but it can also cause problems if rows are updated in the source system and the audit column is not changed.  I recommend only trusted it if it has a trigger or you can be certain that no human can perform updates on the table.

Additionally, this component falls short when there is a lot of columns to map or a lot of transforms going on in the data flow.  For example, if you are converting all string columns from unicode to non-unicode, you may have many additional columns in the mix that will make mapping and maintenance a pain.  The mapping tool in this component is good for about 10 columns, it starts to get confusing very quickly after that.  Especially because you are mapping to numbered parameters rather than column names.

Lastly, if you are doing anything complex in the update statement, it is better suited for SQL code rather than maintaining it in the components editor which has no intellisense and is generally painful to use.

2) Stage the data and perform the update in Execute SQL task after the data flow

This method is good for all the reasons that the OLEDB command is bad for, but has some disadvantages as well.  There is more code to maintain:

- a couple of t-sql tasks,
- a proc
- and a staging table

This means also that it takes more time to set up as well.  However, it does perform very well and the code is far easier to read and understand.  Ongoing maintenance is simpler as well.

Please see my notes from this other question that I happened to answer today on the same subject:  [SSIS Compare tables content and update another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429881/ssis-compare-tables-content-and-update-another/28433501)